# Developing a Chromecast Server

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, google-cast, chromecast

i want to develop a Chromecast server, written in C++ with the help of the Nokia QT5 framework. SSDP and HTTP is working, i can switch and play movies on YouTube via the Android YouTube app, but the Chrome Browser extension, the Android app "RemoteCast", the Chromecast setup tool for Windows and the Google Music app on Android can't find my Server. Both of the apps find my Server, get the device description xml content but nothing happens. The Chrome Browser extension gets successfully the application path ("/apps/Chromecast"), it returns the desired JSON string as response when asked for - but, after that, the remote URL says i should need a receiver id.

Can someone help me with that?

I need a working device description and answers to the these questions:

- What is the UUID for, sent by the USN header and sent by the device description?
- MUST be the UUID different sent by response headers and the device description?
- What "dial" services in the device description are needed? -> both the descriptions from CheapCast and LeapCast aren't working to find my virtual device

Thank you all for help me or trying to do things :)

#### EDIT

UUID's are some nonsense, seems there are never used by the device :D
DIAL services are working so far, device is now found by the ChromeCast browser extension and the Android YouTube app :)

Comment: Development has started already, i can start,stop and play YouTube movies - ChromeCast extension lacks of encoding/decoding of frames for the Web socket part - but it's working so far :)